# Looking for Linux tools to visualize GPS+compass+focal-length EXIF data?

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, jpg, exif

I have JPG images tagged with GPS and compass Exif-data. I took these images in a remote country especially to use it for mapping OSM. Now I am looking for a tool that would help me to use these images effectively:

I would like to see

1. an areal background image,
2. a dot using the GPS coordinates,
3. an arrow pointing to where the camera was looking (compass),
4. and a circular sector into compass direction that represents zoom/focal
   length.

I have only ever seen these features in [GeoSetter beta](http://www.geosetter.de/download/) on Windows. But using Geosetter on Linux is not easy to run (background map missing) and also it is not really actively developed nor is it open-source.

Does anyone know a tool or set of tools to accomplish this on Linux?

Any recommendation for a QGis plugin that can do some of the features (so I might actually extend it myself)?

Answer (score 4):

1. QuickMapServices plugin with contributed services added in Settings for the aerial background.
2. Photo2Shape or Geotag and import photos to get a point layer from exif gps coordinates.
3. Duplicate the point layer and change styling from dot symbol to arrow symbol (not nice, but an arrow). Set "Angle" for the simple marker to the imported compass field.
4. Python magic?

Answer (score 4):

[Gps Prune](http://activityworkshop.net/software/gpsprune/) is a nice, peformant tool (java) to work with photos - especially since an export as csv is quick, to further process in qgis. Not sure about working with the angle etc.

Answer (score 3):

The JOSM editor for OSM can be used as well, although it does not have support for the focal length